# When do injective and projective tensor norms agree?

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

For $C^*$-algebra tensor products, one talks about the min and max tensor norms, and they agree when one of the $C^*$-algebras is nuclear. For general Banach algebras, what is the analog of nuclearity? Is there a similar (or other) condition under which the injective and projective tensor norms agree?